Pandas - Change specific input based on row and column name
Lets say I have the following dataframe
data = [['Tom', 180], ['Adam', 174], ['Bob', 182]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Height'])

If I wish to change the value of Bob's height, I could use .at as follows:
df.at[2, 'Height'] = 190. However since every name is unique, Im looking for a way to do something along the line of
df.at['Bob', 'Height'] = 190. After tinkering with I bit, I ended up opting to first find the location of Bob within df and then use its location along side .at
location = np.where(df['Name'].values == 'Bob')[0][0]
df.at[location, 'Height'] = 190

However, There must be a better way to do this. Note that I am not adamant on the use of .at property. I think my solution is reasonable, but I want to know if there is something better out there.
After playing with it some more I found this
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Bob', 'Height'] = 190

I am quite happy with this. Clearly this method would cause issues if I had repeats. But fortunately I do not.

If name is unique, using it as an index looks best for update.

@PandaKim That is probably the best way to do it. I'm mad i didn't realize that right away.
